# Collection of matrices generate reducible SU(3) representation

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Considering the collection of matrices (defined in the six dimensional tensor product space) $T_a = \frac{1}{2} \lambda_a \otimes \sigma_2$ and $T_i = \frac{1}{2} \lambda_i \otimes I$ where $\lambda_a$ are the $SU(3)$ generating Gell-Mann matrices for $a=1,3,4,6,8$, $\lambda_i$ are the Gell-Mann matrices for $i=2,5,7$, and $\sigma_2$ is the Pauli matrix. I'm asked to show that these generate a reducible representation of SU(3), and to reduce it.

There are a few things I can pick out from the matrices, mainly that $[T_i,T_j] = i\epsilon_{ijk} T_k$ for $\{i,j,k\} = \{2,5,7\}$, and $[T_a,T_b] = if_{abk} T_k$ for $\{a,b\} = \{1,3,4,6,8\}$ and $k=2,5,7$, where (I think) the $f_{abc}$ are undetermined.

The first comes from the fact that $\lambda_{2,5,7}$ generate an $SU(2)$  subalgebra of $SU(3)$. For the second, we know that $T_a$ are symmetric, so $[T_a,T_b]^T = -[T_a,T_b]$ and this means that if $[T_a,T_b] = i\epsilon_{abc} T_c$ ; then $T_c$ must be antisymmetric, and the antisymmetric $T_c$s are the $T_i$s.

Also, $[T_a,T_i] = i\epsilon_{aic} T_c$ for $c=1,3,4,6,8$ by the same idea as above, since $[T_a,T_i]^T = [T_a,T_i]$.

I'm struggling with using this information to reduce this representation of SU(3).

Gell-Mann matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices

Comment: Please provide links for the used matrices. The $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is also happy to act as an index. Please mention which is the group acting by the given matrices on which space over which field.

Comment: You still have not specified what group (or maybe Lie algebra since you seem to be taking some Lie brackets?) these are meant to be representations of.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what edit I need to make? This is some "arbitrary" collection of matrices, which are tensor products of the $SU(3)$ generating Gell-Mann matrices, and the Pauli matrix $\sigma_2$. I don't know if this representation generates a specific group, or what it reduces to.

Comment: A reducible representation is not a meaningful thing on its own. A representation is something associated to a group (or Lie algebra or various other objects). And you have not apparently specified the group here (while one could in principle avoid this, we still need to know if this is meant to be the representation of a group or of a Lie algebra for example).

Comment: Then I imagine this is asking to show that these matrices generate a reducible representation of $SU(3)$, but in the six dimensional space. I'm learning from a text on the applications of Lie algebras to particle physics; a lot is implied in the questions in the text, like this one for example, so I may be assuming things without realizing I was assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! Inspection of the structure constants *f* of SU(3) in the Gell-Mann basis confirms that they must vanish unless they contain an odd number of indices from the set  $  \{2,5,7\}$, those of the imaginary generators. This is because the commutation relation includes an *i* on the r.h.s., so it must involve one or three imaginary generators.

So, indeed, as you observed, $[\lambda_i,\lambda_j] = i\epsilon_{ijk} \lambda_k$  ;   $[\lambda_a,\lambda_b] = i2f_{abk} \lambda_k$ ; and $[\lambda_a,\lambda_i] = i2f_{aib} \lambda_b$.

Now, the imaginary $\sigma_2$s square to the identity, and therefore clearly preserve the Lie algebra of the *λ*/2s in transitioning to the *T*s. That is, the all-imaginary *T*s provide a representation of SU(3), as well.

The unitary group matrices $\exp (i\vec \theta\cdot \vec T)$ are thus real, sending real 6-vectors to real vectors. But you already know the irreducible **6** of SU(3) is complex--immediately visible from its Young tableau.

You can immediately see, by inspection, that the representation is reducible, if you appreciate $\sigma_2$ is equivalent to $\sigma_3$, diag(1,-1); so, if you moved the 2d matrices to the left of the direct product, the upper 3 components of the vectors in your 6d vector space never mix with the lower 3 ones under action of the group matrices. That is, your *T* matrices consist of an upper left 3×3 block acting on the upper 3 components and an identical but opposite lower right 3×3 block acting on the lower 3.

So what is the similarity transformation reducing *T* to this visibly reduced *T'*?

- You can easily prove that 
  $$
  S\equiv ( \mathbb{1} +i\sigma_1)/\sqrt{2} , \qquad S^\dagger S=\mathbb{1} ~,\qquad S^\dagger \sigma_2 S=\sigma_3. 
  $$

Consequently the unitary 6×6 matrix $\mathbb{1}_3\otimes S$ will provide the requisite similarity transformation.

Your representation reduces to a triplet and a mirror-image triplet!

Comment: Thanks, this is a good explanation! I didn't realize all the $T$s were imaginary by their construction at first. Can we change the order of the tensor product because the two matrices are square, so they are permutation similar? (Took that from Wikipedia.)

Comment: Nothing in their algebraic treatment depends on the order of the product... two disjoint spaces. You stick matrices of one, consistently, into elements of the other, but it does not matter which!

Comment: Well, if you do $\frac{1}{2} \lambda_a \otimes \sigma_2$ it is different than $\sigma_2 \otimes \frac{1}{2} \lambda_a$, but it appears they're related by a similarity transformation - this is because they are square matrices, according to property 2 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product. Since I assume in group theory we will never (I think?) work with matrices that aren't square, this is typically true?

Comment: Indeed, standard lore. Considering the action of these rep matrices on 6-vectors and the relabelling permutation of their components makes the point self-evident.